# ifelse gives different output in different function

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

What I want to do:

A vector with length greater than 1 will be converted into (0,1) range.

But I only get the first value.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com) discussed the problem, but I found no way to solve mine.

The following code is used.

```
x <- 1:10
x
range01 <- function(x) { (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) }
range01(x)
ifelse(length(x) > 1, range01(x), x)

[1] 0
```

I get only the first value.

However, the following ifelse gives a vector, which I used as a test.

```
ifelse(x >= 0, sqrt(x), NA)

[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751 
    2.828427 3.000000 3.162278
```

Comment: I'm suspecting you want `if(length(x)>1) range01(x) else x` not `ifelse` the function.

Comment: I think you want ‘if(length(x)>1) range01(x) else x‘. Ifelse is a vectorized function which expects a vector of tests (usually longer than length 1)

Comment: The two tests in your examples are not equivalent. `length(x)>1` returns a single value while `x >= 0` returns a vector of the same length as `x`. @thelatemail suggestion will work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the information given by @Seth, I have a solution now. I created a vectorized output from the condition `length(x)>1`

```
ifelse(rep(length(x)>1, length(x)), range01(x), x)
```